# How to properly build a dataframe in ggplot to plot different charts

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I'm running a lot of simulations in the field of electrical systems using PSS/E. Currently, I'm on the phase of treating the captured data to visualize it.

I have already investigated over the Internet. I've also seen a lot of examples on how to build different plots using `ggplot` in python, but none of those tutorials or examples seem to care much about the dataframe construction.

The following code does plot a chart as expected for me.

```py
    def plot_default_example(self):
        islands = ['LPA', 'LPA', 'LPA', 'LPA', 'LPA', 'LPA',
                   'TNF', 'TNF', 'TNF', 'TNF', 'TNF', 'TNF',
                   'GOM', 'GOM', 'GOM', 'GOM', 'GOM', 'GOM']
        years = [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
                 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
                 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
        population = []
        for _ in range(0, 18):
            population.append(randint(1500, 15000))
        print years
        print population
        df = pd.DataFrame({'island': islands, 'years': years, 'population': population})
        plt = ggplot(df, aes(x='years', y='population', color='island')) +\
            geom_line() + labs(title='Random Population in 3 of the Canary Islands from 2014 to 2019')
        print plt
```

[image: plot of random population over a few years in 3 of the canary islands]

As you might realize, in the dataframe there is a lot of redundant because the years and islands are repeated, but it is the only way I know how to do it.

I was wondering if there is any way to avoid such redundancy.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'years': [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
                           'Population_GOM': [155, 785, 452, 958, 254, 635],
                            'Population_LPA': [777, 444, 123, 734, 697, 148],
                            'Population_TNF': [1005, 85, 321, 478, 307, 448]
                           })


        df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='years')
        print df
        plt = ggplot(aes(x='years', y='value', color='variable'), df) + \
            geom_line()
        print plt
```

Being the output, (note that is not the same population data)

[image]